# cannot convert datatype from float to string

Tags: c#

I want to change the value of total price's text box when unit price and quantity is entered.Unit price and total price's data type is float.
This code show error tht cannot convert int to float
how i can solve this issue?

```
Txtbox_quantity_textchanged
{

   TxttotalPrice.text= (a*b).toString();

}
```

Comment: You also use type cast means `TxttotalPrice.text=  (float )(a*b).toString();`

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? There is a built-in `object` method named `ToString`, but you are not using that, you are using `toString`. What is `toString`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see where is the problem, since you're unclear.

the following code compiles and runsL

```
float floatNumber =  60;
int intNumber = 34;
string result = (intNumber*floatNumber).ToString();
```

If you're having other trouble try casting:

```
float floatNumber =  60;
int intNumber = 34;
float result = (float) intNumber*floatNumber;
string newResult = result.ToString();
```